# CodeIgniter Form not redirecting properly to paypal

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, paypal

I'm making an ebook online shop with the payment gateway *PayPal*. Before the user buys my book, I want them to sign up and I want to save their info into my db. This is the code that I've copied from [`developer.paypal.com`](http://developer.paypal.com).

```
 <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
            <div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="buyer_first_name" required id="mailchimp-fname">
              <br/>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="buyer_last_name" required id="mailchimp-lname">
             <br/>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required name="buyer_email" id="mailchimp-email">
              <br/>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
              SIGN UP USING FACEBOOK
            </button>
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----MIIHfwYJKoZIhvcNAQcEoIIHcDCCB2wCAQExggEwMIIBLAIBADCBlDCBjjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxCzAJBgNVBAgTAkNBMRYwFAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtQYXlQYWwgSW5jLjETMBEGA1UECxQKbGl2ZV9jZXJ0czERMA8GA1UEAxQIbGl2ZV9hcGkxHDAaBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWDXJlQHBheXBhbC5jb20CAQAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAEgYBVbgVO+woc2RO3nt25dc/ecCHPcgXM04uhn+kAIea4MqSCPydnM5+9UwuGNK6IdVMGy6rgqGkwRInAMA40mgGdfA+nm/5RjvTYAr3ZorvRojc1sYpJt/K/z8YYqRNXE8ohOBni8hEhVY4zdPT908k8HNahi2P3ZpPybqe2PdQjADELMAkGBSsOAwIaBQAwgfwGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAUBggqhkiG9w0DBwQI13xabhbr7+aAgdhmI67QHmKFtDedBgCl1tXuaHjiT4Jav1lMB2bLj0PKUnDZBwees6OiSYdc/H7OVgKiRsngUo+WzNxJFXXM0aKUV7uWyQm3+odPmtZ85ROe2IDeBJvhyCutCz8DCdY2m4SspTE5Qjfc+RzMqlHMFk+8jzFE6zHGuZbPFkNv3Rc9IM/AVdTFVYqg1GNlg0oMr9DfJoa/Z5J4zKmA9C7jYL0/pHRIconZsFLV/4O7JrrJZHE/RS5DBjbu0Fy+XIyBl1c2vjfhkOMAipq3oqHgHFZuU9gB1X5WG5CgggOHMIIDgzCCAuygAwIBAgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBjjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxCzAJBgNVBAgTAkNBMRYwFAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtQYXlQYWwgSW5jLjETMBEGA1UECxQKbGl2ZV9jZXJ0czERMA8GA1UEAxQIbGl2ZV9hcGkxHDAaBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWDXJlQHBheXBhbC5jb20wHhcNMDQwMjEzMTAxMzE1WhcNMzUwMjEzMTAxMzE1WjCBjjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxCzAJBgNVBAgTAkNBMRYwFAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtQYXlQYWwgSW5jLjETMBEGA1UECxQKbGl2ZV9jZXJ0czERMA8GA1UEAxQIbGl2ZV9hcGkxHDAaBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWDXJlQHBheXBhbC5jb20wgZ8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADgY0AMIGJAoGBAMFHTt38RMxLXJyO2SmS+Ndl72T7oKJ4u4uw+6awntALWh03PewmIJuzbALScsTS4sZoS1fKciBGoh11gIfHzylvkdNe/hJl66/RGqrj5rFb08sAABNTzDTiqqNpJeBsYs/c2aiGozptX2RlnBktH+SUNpAajW724Nv2Wvhif6sFAgMBAAGjge4wgeswHQYDVR0OBBYEFJaffLvGbxe9WT9S1wob7BDWZJRrMIG7BgNVHSMEgbMwgbCAFJaffLvGbxe9WT9S1wob7BDWZJRroYGUpIGRMIGOMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzELMAkGA1UECBMCQ0ExFjAUBgNVBAcTDU1vdW50YWluIFZpZXcxFDASBgNVBAoTC1BheVBhbCBJbmMuMRMwEQYDVQQLFApsaXZlX2NlcnRzMREwDwYDVQQDFAhsaXZlX2FwaTEcMBoGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYNcmVAcGF5cGFsLmNvbYIBADAMBgNVHRMEBTADAQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4GBAIFfOlaagFrl71+jq6OKidbWFSE+Q4FqROvdgIONth+8kSK//Y/4ihuE4Ymvzn5ceE3S/iBSQQMjyvb+s2TWbQYDwcp129OPIbD9epdr4tJOUNiSojw7BHwYRiPh58S1xGlFgHFXwrEBb3dgNbMUa+u4qectsMAXpVHnD9wIyfmHMYIBmjCCAZYCAQEwgZQwgY4xCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMQswCQYDVQQIEwJDQTEWMBQGA1UEBxMNTW91bnRhaW4gVmlldzEUMBIGA1UEChMLUGF5UGFsIEluYy4xEzARBgNVBAsUCmxpdmVfY2VydHMxETAPBgNVBAMUCGxpdmVfYXBpMRwwGgYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFg1yZUBwYXlwYWwuY29tAgEAMAkGBSsOAwIaBQCgXTAYBgkqhkiG9w0BCQMxCwYJKoZIhvcNAQcBMBwGCSqGSIb3DQEJBTEPFw0xNTA2MDYxOTEyNTBaMCMGCSqGSIb3DQEJBDEWBBTmyZ2VXSFUpV0WogL+Mp/Y6CZC1TANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASBgI4qMxl59Fc9D8gsHZP/+j0sZ8guShv0UqFJg5m51jCPmVTvXDo+r/D1hdWpUUw9zgesPeKg0gacWokehP80YvwUNw/+8NphyiRux1rY0WNHn2kDZ0lhfs8DHff28I55oIckGI93aan4aqmtZUGpGvbcF+E5wfXoTStniBgjgGyQ-----END PKCS7-----
            ">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="BUY" class="btn btn-default">
          </form>
```

And when the user submits the form it takes me to the checkout from PayPal 
[image]

Which is good and that's what I want, but I also want to insert their signed form fields into my database so I changed the code a little bit. This is my view code:

```
  <?php echo form_open('welcome/the_buyer')?>
            <div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="buyer_first_name" required id="mailchimp-fname">
              <br/>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="buyer_last_name" required id="mailchimp-lname">
             <br/>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required name="buyer_email" id="mailchimp-email">
              <br/>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
              SIGN UP USING FACEBOOK
            </button>
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----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-----END PKCS7-----
            ">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="BUY" class="btn btn-default">
          </form>
```

My controller code:

```
  public function the_buyer(){

    $data['buyer_first_name'] = $this->input->post('buyer_first_name');
    $data['buyer_last_name']  = $this->input->post('buyer_last_name');
    $data['buyer_email']      = $this->input->post('buyer_email');
    $this->load->model('buyers_db/buyers');
    $this->buyers->insert($data);
    redirect('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');

}
```

My model code:

```
public function insert($data){

        $this->db->insert('buyers',$data);

    }
```

And now when the user submits the form, the field values are inserting into my database but now the page is redirecting me to this home page
[image]

Comment: Use js ajax function on submit button.

Comment: your code is submitting your form to paypal site.`redirect('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');` it just redirects(get method) to paypal site not submitting the form.Paypal does not get any value so it redirects you to its homepage

Comment: so how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The form needs to submit directly to PayPal, not your site. You will need to utilize the `notify` url or the `return` link to process the payment and insert any information in the database.

For more information on `PayPal IPN` I suggest you check out [this link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/).

You'll want to include any data you want to store in the custom field of the form. I recommend, storing something like the user_id, or an encrypted user_id so that when the `notify` pings back to your website, you can read what is in `custom`, and use that to insert data into the database. Please note, this field may be tampered with, so remember to sanitize it, or encrypt it so users can't change the data.

Answer (score 0):

i wasn't redirecting to the right url

```
 redirect('https://www.paypal.com/pe/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=S-A8TQJiOMvvMRh8VUV6-8W01hNHYgkK0ZVirABunW_IjHIcFecUT9cfGxm&dispatch=50a222a57771920b6a3d7b606239e4d529b525e0b7e69bf0224adecfb0124e9b61f737ba21b08198acc59b45c1b5383c3fbf91319c9514c0');
```

Thanks for the help everybody